# Attempting to create lu decomposition inverse matrix using C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Crout_method(float original[20][20], float L[20][20], float U[20][20], int dim);

int main(){
    int i,column, row, mul_index; int dim = 4;
    float L[20][20] = { {0,} }; float U[20][20] = { {0,} };
    float inverse[20][20], L_inverse[20][20], U_inverse[20][20];
    float multiplied[20][20] ,ftemp;
    float original[20][20] = { {-1,-2,-4,1},{2,7,14,4},{1,4,9,6},{4,10,17,-5} };
    printf("* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * \n");
    printf("Entered matrix A is : \n");
    for (row = 0; row < dim; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < dim; column++) {
            printf("%10.3f ", original[row][column]);
            ftemp = original[row][column];
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    Crout_method(original, L, U, dim);
    for (row = 0; row < dim; row++)
        L_inverse[row][row] = 1.0 / L[row][row];

    for (column = 0; column < dim - 1; column++) {
        for (row = column + 1; row < dim; row++) {
            ftemp = 0;
            for (i = column; i < row; i++)
                ftemp += L[row][i] * L_inverse[i][column];
            L_inverse[row][column] = -1.0 * ftemp / L[row][row];
        }
    }
    for (row = 0; row < dim; row++)
        U_inverse[row][row] = 1.0;


    for (row = 0; row < dim - 1; row++) {
        for (column = row + 1; column < dim; column++) {
            ftemp = 0;
            for (i = row; i < column; i++)
                ftemp += U_inverse[row][i] * U[i][column];
            U_inverse[row][column] = -1.0 * ftemp;
        }
    }
    for (row = 0; row < dim; row++)
        for (column = 0; column < dim; column++) {
            inverse[row][column] = 0;
            for (mul_index = 0; mul_index < dim; mul_index++)
                inverse[row][column] += U_inverse[row][mul_index] * L_inverse[mul_index][column];
        }
    for(row = 0; row < dim; row++ )
    for (column = 0; column < dim; column++) {
        multiplied[row][column] = 0;
        for (mul_index = 0; mul_index < dim; mul_index++)
            multiplied[row][column] += L[row][mul_index] * U[mul_index][column];
    }
        printf("\n\n* * ***** * *** *** ***** ***********\n");
        printf("\n L matrix of A is : \n");
        for(row = 0; row < dim; row++){
        for (column = 0; column < dim; column++)
            printf("%10.3f ", L[row][column]);
        printf("\n");
        }
        printf(" \n\n* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * \n");
        printf("\n U matrix of A is : \n");
        for(row = 0; row < dim; row++){
        for (column = 0; column < dim; column++)
            printf("%10.3f ", U[row][column]);
        printf("\n");
        }
        printf(" \n\n* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * \n");
        printf("Inverse matrix of L matrix is :\n");
        for (row = 0; row < dim; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < dim; column++)
                printf("%10.3f", L_inverse[row][column]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n\n********** ***********************\n");
        printf("Inverse matrix of U matrix is :\n");
        for (row = 0; row < dim; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < dim; column++)
                printf("%10.3f", U_inverse[row][column]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        //getch();
        printf(" \n\n* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * ** * * * * \n");
        printf("Inverse matrix of matrix A is :\n");
        for (row = 0; row < dim; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < dim; column++)
                printf("%10.3f ", inverse[row][column]);
            printf("\n");
        }
            printf("\n\n* + * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *\n");
        printf("multiplication of matrix L and matrix U is :\n");
        for (row = 0; row < dim; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < dim; column++)
                printf("%10.3f ", multiplied[row][column]);
            printf("\n");
        }
}
void Crout_method(float original[20][20], float L[20][20], float U[20][20], int dim) {
    int i, row, column;
    float ftemp;
    for (row = 0; row < dim; row++)
        L[row][0] = original[row][0];
    for (row = 0; row < dim; row++)
        U[row][row] = 1.0;
    for (column = 1; column < dim; column++)
        U[0][column] = original[0][column] / original[0][0];
    for (column = 1; column < dim; column++) {
        for (row = column; row < dim; row++) {
            ftemp = 0.0;
            for (i = 0; i < column; i++)
                ftemp += L[row][i] * U[i][column];
            L[row][column] = original[row][column] - ftemp;
        }
        for (row = column + 1; row < dim; row++) {
            ftemp = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < column; i++)
                ftemp += L[column][i] * U[i][row];
            ftemp = original[column][row] - ftemp;
            U[column][row] = ftemp / L[column][column];
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to programming.

I am attempting to code a lu decomposition inverse matrix

Except for the inverse proportion, the rest are normal.
But No matter how you modify it, the inverse results show strange numbers.
How am I supposed to handle this?

Compilation error does not occur.

Comment: “the inverse results show strange numbers” is not an adequate problem description. Prepare a [mre]. Reduce the code in the question to just code that shows the problem—remove prior calls and outputs that are not needed. Explain exactly what is wrong with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Compilation error does not occur."*

What about warnings?

> ...
> *"But No matter how you modify it, the inverse* ***results show strange numbers***. *How am I supposed to handle this?"*

When your code is run, the first error I see is this:

[image]

This is at least in part why you are seeing unexpected results.

Turn on all compiler and run-time warnings, then read what they tell you, and address the issue appropriately.

For example, if you are using GCC, compiler settings should include `-Wall`

Below is what my compiler tells me:  Mostly you need to initialize your variables.

For example, change:

```
float multiplied[20][20] ,ftemp;
```

To:

```
float multiplied[20][20] = {{0}} ,ftemp = 0;
```

See following, and address each of them as indicated.

```
Build Status (test.prj - Debug)
 s0_15.c - 10 warnings
  55, 13    warning: variable 'multiplied[row][column]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      10, 1    note: variable 'multiplied' is declared here
  97, 35    warning: variable 'multiplied[row][column]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      10, 1    note: variable 'multiplied' is declared here
  49, 17    warning: variable 'inverse[row][column]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      9, 1    note: variable 'inverse' is declared here
  90, 35    warning: variable 'inverse[row][column]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      9, 1    note: variable 'inverse' is declared here
  41, 26    warning: variable 'U_inverse[row][i]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      9, 1    note: variable 'U_inverse' is declared here
  49, 41    warning: variable 'U_inverse[row][mul_index]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      9, 1    note: variable 'U_inverse' is declared here
  82, 34    warning: variable 'U_inverse[row][column]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      9, 1    note: variable 'U_inverse' is declared here
  29, 38    warning: variable 'L_inverse[i][column]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      9, 1    note: variable 'L_inverse' is declared here
  49, 69    warning: variable 'L_inverse[mul_index][column]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      9, 1    note: variable 'L_inverse' is declared here
  75, 34    warning: variable 'L_inverse[row][column]' may be uninitialized when used here 
      9, 1    note: variable 'L_inverse' is declared here
 Link test.exe
 "c:\Play\test.exe" successfully created.
Build succeeded.
```

Comment: I have a problem with Visual Studio and no problem with VSCODE. Why is that?

Comment: What does VSCODE documentation say?  Compiler / runtimes can differ.

Comment: Previously, I ran it from a Visual Studio 2019.exe, but running it from Visual Studio Code.exe gave me the desired result.